# How do I change the innerText of outer tag in a nested tag line?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html code like this:

```
<p id="phone">Enter your contact number : <input type="tel" id="tel"  style="font-family:cursive;"></input></p>
```

Now I want to change the text `Enter your contact number` to `Enter the OTP received`. So, when I use DOM property in javascript like this:

> document.getElementById("phone").innerText="Enter the OTP received";

The text sure gets changed, but the input text box disappears along with it. I don't want that. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) property and then just replace the first occuring node, which is the text node whose [`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue) you want to replace:

```js
document.getElementById("phone").childNodes[0].nodeValue = 'Enter the OTP received: ';
```

```html
<p id="phone">Enter your contact number: <input type="tel" id="tel"  style="font-family:cursive;"></p>
```

Of course if you want to be *truly* safe, you should double-check the node type (a text node has a `nodeType` of `3`) before performing the replacement:

```js
const node = document.getElementById("phone").childNodes[0];
if (node && node.nodeType === 3) {
  node.nodeValue = 'Enter the OTP received: ';
}
```

```html
<p id="phone">Enter your contact number: <input type="tel" id="tel"  style="font-family:cursive;"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the text node inside the `p`

```js
var p = document.getElementById("phone");

p.replaceChild(document.createTextNode("Enter the OTP received : "), p.firstChild);
```

```html
<p id="phone">Enter your contact number : <input type="tel" id="tel"  style="font-family:cursive;"></input></p>
```